# what's this style of string construction called? foo("xxx %1 xxx %2",arg1,arg2)

Tags: string, function, vba, sequence

I'm blanking on this.  What's the type of string manipulation called where you include a sequence of escaped units in a string, then follow the string with arguments that get substituted into the string when it's processed?

i think it looks like this:

```
foo("xxx %1 yyy %2 zzz %3",arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

ends up as

```
foo("xxx arg1 yyy arg2 zzz arg3")
```

where the values for arg1, arg2, and arg3 have been plugged into those positions in the string.

Whatever it is, I'm trying to figure out how to do it in VBA.

EDIT: It seems it's called "string formatting" or "composite formatting".  Either way, VBA doesn't have this feature, as far as i can tell.

Comment: The name "format string" comes to mind; varies by environment.

Comment: Well actually *foo* is the function replacing the placeholders, so it ends up as *"xxx arg1 yyy zzz arg3"*

Comment: For the edited part: it's not intrinsic to VBA, but you can easily emulate it if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is a `Format()` method - which accepts a format string and collection of parameters.

In C# it is a static method accessible as

```
String.Format()
```

Comment: This got me to the answer to my original question, before I added the part about VBA, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is close to, but not probably exactly the same as, what is called *interpolation* in Perl.

Does this help? http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html

Agreed that it is *not* just formatting!

Answer (score 0):

It's called "composite formating", and no, VBA indeed does not support it. You can use concatenation just as easily:

```
foo = "I went to " & placename & "and bought a " & itemname & "."
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably call it "printf-like".